# Assembly Alternative To Using MOV and JMP

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Currently I have this code to place the address of my function into memory using MOV and JMP. My question is are there any alternatives to MOV or JMP that I could use? Could this be done with LEA and if so how? Thank you!

```
BYTE orig[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; // 12 bytes being replaced

BYTE code[] = { 0x48, 0xB8 }; //MOV RAX
BYTE code_end[] = { 0xFF, 0xE0 }; // JMP RAX

RtlSecureZeroMemory(&orig, sizeof(orig));
memcpy((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)orig), &code, sizeof(code));

uintptr_t hook_address = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(kernel_function_address);

memcpy((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)orig + sizeof(code)), &hook_address, sizeof(void*));
memcpy((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)orig + sizeof(code) + sizeof(void*)), code_end, sizeof(code_end));
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `LEA` instead of `MOV` if you like. Not sure why you'd want to unless you need rip-relative address but then you could just use a relative jump. Instead of `JMP` you can use the stack and `RET`.

Comment: Can you just do `(*kernel_function_address)(); return;` (in plain old C) and let the compiler do tail-call optimization for you?

Comment: Note: You can't use `LEA`  because you have a 64-bit address and `LEA` will only support 32-bit offsets. For the same reason; you also can't use a normal `MOV` and must use `MOVABS` (which I think you are - the comment is just misleading).

Comment: @Brendan: In Intel syntax, `mov r64, imm64` is just another form of `mov`, not a separate `movabs` mnemonic (`rex.w` form of the no-modrm register-only `B8+ rd` encoding, which yes this is).  It's not "misleading", it's simply not using AT&T mnemonics.  But good point about LEA; unless a RIP-relative LEA reaches, or the address fits in a 32-bit sign-extended displacement.  Of course if RIP-relative reaches, just use `jmp rel32`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done with `LEA`. Since I assume this is on the Windows operating system, addresses within the same usermode process module will never be more than a 32 bit offset apart. (You shall not attempt to modify kernel memory anyways, that would have severe consequences). That means 32-bit offsets, which is what `LEA` uses, will be enough. To do so, first choose a register, for the sake of simplicity let's choose `RCX`. Then reference the jump target as such:

`LEA RCX, MY_JUMP_TARGET`

This will effectively give you a shorter piece of assembly than a 10 byte mov and save space. After this, simply jump:

`JMP RCX`

. What about an alternative to `JMP`? You can use the `CALL` instruction like this:

`CALL RCX`

And as a matter of fact, you could actually reduce the entire thing to a single `CALL` or `JMP`, since these instructions not only support general purpose registers as operands, but also direct offsets:

`CALL MY_JUMP_TARGET`

or

`JMP MY_JUMP_TARGET`

(Please note: Using a `CALL` instruction will push the return address on the stack, and as such you'll need to match it with a `RET`.)

PS. I won't provide a copy-pastable solution that you can paste, that's not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: x86-64 has 64-bit addresses.  The "low half" is 63 bits.  (Or really 47 bits for the low half of the canonical range).  Unless the process is non-LargeAddressAware, you can't count on a 32-bit displacement holding an address, as Brendan pointed out in comments.  It sounds like you're thinking about 32-bit mode, but using 64-bit register names.  `jmp rel32` is only usable if the destination is within +-2GiB of where this code lives, which is *not* guaranteed in 64-bit code.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, my bad, I meant that addresses within the same usermode process module are never more than a 32 bit offset apart.

Comment: Ok, but that's only true for symbols within the main executable, or within one DLL.  A buffer you `malloc` to JIT some machine code into could be anywhere.  And a DLL can be loaded more than 2GiB away from the main executable.  (Unless you disable LargeAddressAware so the process can only use < 4GiB *total* memory).  I don't really know Windows, but I think that's how it works.

Comment: But yes, if a RIP-relative LEA can reach, then you might as well use a relative (direct) JMP or CALL in the first place.  Both ways require calculating the *relative* address between the ends of the instruction and the target address, unlike the OP's original where they can just memcpy in an *absolute* address.  It looks like the OP is doing code-gen in C with a template, *not* using an assembler, so your MASM syntax is possibly not as helpful as possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, I'll leave that as an exercise. Oh yeah, a dll or the main executable would be one module which is what I meant.

Comment: And BTW, providing a copy-pastable solution *is* something to avoid for homework questions, but otherwise is common on SO for questions that are actually interesting and useful to future readers.  Not that it's necessary here, it's not 100% clear what constraints the OP might be able to take advantage of.